# .htaccess Access Control does nothing on Debian Stable Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, debian-squeeze

I have a Debian Stable with its regular Apache2 server running. It works fine otherwise, it just does nothing with a `.htaccess` that I put into a directory (`/var/www/admin/`. It says:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName admin
AuthUserFile /var/www/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And in the same folder there is the `.htpasswd` in the same folder.

I checked the `/var/log/apache/error.log`, but it does not show anything.

I added a

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

to the `apache.conf`, but that did not change anything either.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you remember to restart apache after adding the

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

to your configuration ? The only way I can reproduce what you see is to do this. As soon as I restart apache it all starts working as expected.

EDIT: based on the comments it looks like  the directives above have been added to the wrong file. They have been added to `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` rather than the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file.

Comment: I did a `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` and it did not complain about a malformed config. Is there a difference between `apache.conf` and `httpd.conf` maybe?

Comment: You want to put the directive in the vhost configuration file that relates to this particular host. If you have only one site then this is probably /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default (or similar).

Comment: I do not have any vhosts (never used it). I just have the vanilla `127.0.0.1` running. Do I need to create a vhost?

Comment: You will probably find that you are using the default vhost which is located in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

Comment: Ah, there is such a file and it has `AllowOverride None`. That makes all sense now. Wow, Debian *is* a server fortress.

Comment: Problem solved ?

Comment: I have to get to the computer next Thursdays, I can't do anything before that.